# FiscalYear Calendar in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement to create a Financial year  Calendar with

`start date = 2019-03-31 and end_date = 2020-03-28`

```
declare @startdate date = '2019-03-30'
declare @enddate date = '2020-03-28'
declare @dates table (date date, MonthNo int)
while @startdate < @enddate
BEGIN
set @startdate = dateadd(dd,1,@startdate)
insert @dates (date)
select  @startdate
END
select * from @dates
```

I will need to populate month number column

MonthNumber : In this case, It can not be obtained through typical query using

```
DATEPART(MONTH, [date])
```

Requirement : Month number should be starting at 1 and should be assigned as shown below

```
NoOfDays    trading_month
28            1
28            2
35            3
28            4
28            5
35            6
28            7
28            8
35            9
28           10
28           11
35           12
```

Ex: Trading month = 1 is between `2019-03-31 and 2019-04-28` and next 28 days = month 2 and next 35 days month = 3 etc..

ps: I do not want to use case statement 12 times to populate month number, is there any alternate way to achieve this
can achieve this way

```
select *,  case when ROW_NUMBER() over (order by date) between 1 and  28 then 1 
                when ROW_NUMBER() over (order by date) between 29 and 28+28 then 2
                when ROW_NUMBER() over (order by date) between 28+28+1 and  28+29+35 then 3 
                ----so on 
                end MonthNo
from @dates
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option.

**Example**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2019-03-31'


Select [Date]=DateAdd(DAY,Row_Number() over (Order by M,D)-1,@Date1)
      ,[Year]=DatePart(YEAR,@Date1)
      ,[Month]=M
 From (
         Select *
          From (Select Top (28) D=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) From  master..spt_values n1  ) A 
         Cross Join  (Values (1),(2),(4),(5),(7),(8),(10),(11)) B(M)
        Union All 
         Select *
          From ( Select Top (35) D=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) From  master..spt_values n1 ) A 
         Cross Join  (Values (3),(6),(9),(12)) B(M)
      ) A
 Order by 1,2
```

Returns

```
Date        Year    Month
2019-03-31  2019    1
2019-04-01  2019    1
2019-04-02  2019    1
2019-04-03  2019    1
2019-04-04  2019    1
2019-04-05  2019    1
2019-04-06  2019    1
2019-04-07  2019    1
2019-04-08  2019    1
2019-04-09  2019    1
...
2020-03-21  2019    12
2020-03-22  2019    12
2020-03-23  2019    12
2020-03-24  2019    12
2020-03-25  2019    12
2020-03-26  2019    12
2020-03-27  2019    12
2020-03-28  2019    12
```

Comment: This absolutely makes sense, can you please explain other how to read the question, Jim and John , perfect answers. Thanks for this

Comment: @Ven Happy to help.  I've seen patterns like this before,  15 years in the banking industry, you get to see how many organizations run.

Comment: exactly John, every organisation is different, lot people think SQL date table is just as easy as why and how, instead of fitting business requirements. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

Lucky you ... Download and execute the code in my article [SQL Server Calendar Table](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12267/SQL-Server-Calendar-Table.html), then download and modify the code in [SQL Server Calendar Table:  Fiscal Years](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12265/SQL-Server-Calendar-Table-Fiscal-Years.html) to fit your definition of a fiscal year and execute that.

I once had a client that ran on 'Crop year' where their fiscal years started the last week of May, and the only way to pull that off was to create a wompload of T-SQL to populate a Calendar table.  Once that was done for any given dataset all I had to do was JOIN on the date column and then I could get all the fiscal-related column values I wanted without having to recalculate them every time.

{edit:  Here's the relevant code that creates the 4-4-5 from the above Fiscal Weeks article}

```
USE calendar
GO

/*
Calendar table:  Populate the six fiscal_ columns
2015-09-16  
*/

Declare @dtYearStart date, @dtStart date, @dtEnd date, @dt date
Declare @fiscal_month tinyint = 1, @fiscal_year smallint , @fiscal_week_in_month tinyint, @fiscal_week_in_year tinyint, @fiscal_day_in_week tinyint, @fiscal_day_in_month tinyint
Declare @counter int = 1, @counter_year int = 1, @counter_month int = 1, @counter_week int = 1, @counter_day int = 1

-- Run this for 19 years from May 2000 to May 2020
WHILE @counter_year <= 19 
begin

   -- Per the article image, the last day of the year is the last Sunday in May. 
   SELECT @dtYearStart = MAX(PKDate), @dtEnd = MAX(PKDate)
   FROM days
   WHERE continuous_year = @counter_year AND calendar_month = 5 AND calendar_day_in_week = 1

   -- YEARS and MONTHS

   -- Set the year
   SELECT @fiscal_year = YEAR(@dtYearStart) + 1, @fiscal_month = 1

   SET @counter = 1
   WHILE @counter <= 12
      begin

      SELECT @dtStart = DATEADD(day, 1, @dtEnd)
      SELECT @dtEnd = DATEADD(day, CASE WHEN @fiscal_month IN (1, 4, 7, 10) THEN 34 ELSE 27 END, @dtStart) 

      UPDATE days
      SET fiscal_year = @fiscal_year, fiscal_month = @fiscal_month
      FROM days
      WHERE PKDate >= @dtStart AND PKDate <= @dtEnd

      ;WITH ro AS (SELECT PKDate, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PKDate) as row_order FROM days WHERE fiscal_year = @fiscal_year AND fiscal_month = @fiscal_month)
      UPDATE days
      SET fiscal_day_in_month = row_order
      FROM days
         JOIN ro ON days.PKDate = ro.PKDate 

      -- TESTING ONLY, comment the below line out in production
      -- SELECT 'Year and Month' as label, PKDate, fiscal_year, fiscal_month, fiscal_day_in_month FROM days WHERE PKDate >= @dtStart AND PKDate <= @dtEnd

      SELECT @counter = @counter + 1, @fiscal_month = @fiscal_month + 1

      end


 -- WEEKS
   SELECT @counter = 1, @counter_week = 1, @dtEnd =  @dtYearStart
   WHILE @counter <= 52
      begin

      SELECT @dtStart = DATEADD(day, 1, @dtEnd)
      SELECT @dtEnd = DATEADD(day, 6, @dtStart) 

      UPDATE days
      SET fiscal_week_in_month = @counter_week, fiscal_week_in_year = @counter
      FROM days
      WHERE PKDate >= @dtStart AND PKDate <= @dtEnd

      -- TESTING ONLY, comment the below line out in production
      -- SELECT 'Week' as label, PKDate, fiscal_week_in_year, fiscal_week_in_month FROM days WHERE PKDate >= @dtStart AND PKDate <= @dtEnd

      SELECT @counter = @counter + 1

      -- Get the fiscal month of the row to determine if the month has 4 or 5 weeks.
      SELECT @fiscal_month = fiscal_month FROM days WHERE PKDate = @dtStart

      SELECT @counter_week = CASE 
         WHEN @fiscal_month IN (1, 4, 7, 10) AND @counter_week = 5 THEN 1 
         WHEN @fiscal_month IN (1, 4, 7, 10) AND @counter_week < 5 THEN @counter_week + 1
         WHEN @fiscal_month NOT IN (1, 4, 7, 10) AND @counter_week = 4 THEN 1 
         WHEN @fiscal_month NOT IN (1, 4, 7, 10) AND @counter_week < 4 THEN @counter_week + 1 END

      end

   -- DAYS
   ;WITH ro AS (SELECT PKDate, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PKDate) as row_order FROM days WHERE fiscal_year = @fiscal_year)
   UPDATE days
   SET fiscal_day_in_year = row_order
   FROM days
      JOIN ro ON days.PKDate = ro.PKDate 

   SELECT @counter_year  = @counter_year + 1

   end
```

Good luck.
Jim

Comment: Thanks for this, i have already seen this. This doesn't solve this particular issue. I am trying to find a way instead of hard-coding using case

Comment: Guessing not, as when I built the Crop Year calendar table it was also a 4-4-5 year, and had to do it with CASE blocks within a loop.  In the Fiscal Years article scroll down to 'Hard:  4-4-5 Fiscal Year' and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: This is a great work, i saw your blog. I will accept this answer as it helps further creating other columns and thanks for this.

Comment: No prob.  If you come up with any improvements please let me know and I'll improve my article.  Right now the only thing I have in my pipeline for another article would be a quick-and-dirty cte to do a simple calendar set where months = calendar months.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the expected results with the following query.  The only addition to the original table was an identity column.  Using most of your original code:

```
declare @startdate date = '2019-03-30'
declare @enddate date = '2020-03-28'
declare @dates table (pkindex int IDENTITY(1,1), [date] date, MonthNo tinyint)
while @startdate < @enddate
BEGIN
set @startdate = dateadd(dd,1,@startdate)
insert @dates ([date])
select  @startdate       
END

DECLARE @requirments TABLE (NoOfDays tinyint, trading_month tinyint)
INSERT INTO @requirments VALUES
 (28, 1), (28, 2), (35, 3), (28, 4), (28, 5), (35, 6), (28, 7), (28, 8), (35, 9)
,(28, 10), (28, 11), (35, 12)


UPDATE @dates
   SET MonthNo = 
       (SELECT MIN(R.trading_month)
          FROM @requirments R
         WHERE pkindex < 
               (SELECT SUM(R2.NoOfDays)
                  FROM @requirments R2
                 WHERE R2.trading_month < R.trading_month + 1
               ) + 1
       )

SELECT * FROM @dates
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your goal here exactly, why 1 = 28 specifically. However it seems like your datepart idea was inline with your desired solution if you just do this I get the layout you wanted.

```
declare @startdate date = '2019-03-30'
declare @enddate date = '2020-03-28'
declare @dates table (NoOfDays date, trading_mo int)
while @startdate < @enddate
BEGIN
set @startdate = dateadd(dd,1,@startdate)
insert @dates (NoOfDays)
select  @startdate
END
select count(NoOfDays) noOfDays, 
    datepart(month,NoOfDays) trading_mo 
from @dates 
group by datepart(month,NoOfDays)
order by trading_mo
```

Comment: I am sure u haven't understood the question. The first 28 days should acquire month number1 and next 28 days monthnumber2 and next 35 days monthnumber3 adn so on as mentioned in the above question

Comment: yes, i read your amended question is much different now but do not have another alternative outside jims

Comment: You might wanna read John's answer above, could be useful with different business requirements

Comment: Yes, unioning cross joins tied to the value was creative, I will also thumbs up that.